# How do I configure my CMake project to run all unit tests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake

I have a C++ project using `cmake` as the build tool. My directory structure looks like the following.

```
.
├── cmake-build-debug
├── include
├── src
└── tests
```

When I am inside `cmake-build-debug`, I run `cmake ..` followed by `make clean && make && make test`. What I noticed is that only the first unit test is run. How do I configure my project so that when I run `make test`, all unit tests are run? At the root, my `CMakeLists.txt` looks like the following.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(my_lib)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(tests)

enable_testing()
```

My `tests/CmakeLists.txt` looks like the following (configuration taken from this [website](https://www.neyasystems.com/an-engineers-guide-to-unit-testing-cmake-and-boost-unit-tests/)).

```
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
add_definitions (-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)

include_directories (../include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB TEST_SRCS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)

foreach(testSrc ${TEST_SRCS})
    get_filename_component(testName ${testSrc} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${testName} ${testSrc})

    target_link_libraries(${testName} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} my_lib)

    set_target_properties(${testName} PROPERTIES
            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testBin)

    add_test(NAME ${testName}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testBin
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testBin/${testName}
            )
endforeach(testSrc)
```

The `test` target of `cmake-build-debug/Makefile` that is generated looks like the following.

```
# Special rule for the target test
test:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running tests..."
    /usr/bin/ctest --force-new-ctest-process $(ARGS)
.PHONY : test

# Special rule for the target test
test/fast: test

.PHONY : test/fast
```

The generated `cmake-build-debug/CTestTestfile.cmake` looks like the following.

```
subdirs("src")
subdirs("tests")
```

The generated `cmake-build-debug/src/CTestTestfile.cmake` is empty, but the `cmake-build-debug/tests/CTestTestfile.cmake` has the following content. There are more `test_XYZ.cpp` classes under the `tests` directory, but they are not being added here.

```
add_test(test_Dummy "/path/to/git/my_lib/tests/testBin/test_Dummy")
set_tests_properties(test_Dummy PROPERTIES  WORKING_DIRECTORY "/path/to/git/my_lib/tests/testBin")
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: One thing I notice is that you only need to specify the target *name* in the `add_test()` command: `COMMAND ${testName}`. CMake automatically resolves the target location in this case. You might try naming the test itself something different than the target you're testing with it. Other than that, it may also be helpful to look through your CTestTestfile.cmake file if it was generated.

Comment: `subdirs("src")` in `CTestTestfile.cmake` means to descend into the directory and look the same file in it. What is content of `CTestTestfile.cmake` in the subdirectories?

Comment: Changing `COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testBin/${testName}` to `COMMAND ${testName}` does not change the behavior.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've added the additional `CTestTestfile.cmake` contents. Your hint towards those files show that only 1 test is added.

Comment: Try moving `enable_testing()` before `add_subdirectory`. Just to be sure, you don't set `BUILD_TESTING` anywhere? Debug with `message(STATUS ..)`. Does `${TEST_SRCS}` contain the correct list? Does `${testName}` contain the correct name? Insert `message(STATUS ${TEST_SRCS})` `${testName})` in some places and see the output while `cmake` is configuring. Did you try removing cmake cache files and recreating all?

Comment: To debug, would be good to check if the variable does indeed contain all of your test sources: `message("TEST_SRCS: ${TEST_SRCS}")`

Comment: @KamilCuk That worked! Please post your answer as a response and I will accept it. Simply moving `enable_testing()` before `add_subdirectory()` got all unit tests to run with `make test`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enable_testing()` enables `add_test()` after it. So just make sure you call `enable_testing()` before any `add_test()` you want to enable.