# How do I pass in parameters to change the output of unit tests when using CMake and BOOST?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, cmake

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976311/how-do-i-configure-my-cmake-project-to-run-all-unit-tests), I asked on how to get unit tests with `CMake` and `BOOST` to run. In this question, I need to format the output of the test runs. In particular, the default output is not very insightful and I want to change it; I need to pass in parameters like `--report-level=detailed` when running the tests.

My `tests/CMakeLists.txt` file looks like the following.

```
find_package (Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
add_definitions (-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)

include_directories (../include ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB TEST_SRCS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)

foreach(testSrc ${TEST_SRCS})
    get_filename_component(testName ${testSrc} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${testName} ${testSrc})

    target_link_libraries(${testName} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} my_lib)

    set_target_properties(${testName} PROPERTIES
            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testBin)

    add_test(NAME ${testName}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testBin
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testBin/${testName}
            )
endforeach(testSrc)
```

I have modified it to look as follows. Note I have tried to pass in the arguments in multiple places out of desperation, one during `add_test` and one during `add_custom_command`.

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem unit_test_framework REQUIRED)
add_definitions(-DBOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)

include_directories(../include/graph ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB TEST_SRCS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)

foreach (testSrc ${TEST_SRCS})
    get_filename_component(testName ${testSrc} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${testName} ${testSrc})

    target_link_libraries(${testName} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} my_lib)

    set_target_properties(${testName} PROPERTIES
            RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testBin)

    add_test(NAME ${testName}
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testBin
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/testBin/${testName} --build_info --output_format=XML --log_level=all --report_level=detailed
            )
    add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT ${testName}
            POST_BUILD
            COMMAND ${testName} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/testBin/${testName}
            ARGS "--build_info --output_format=XML --log_level=all --report_level=detailed"
    )
endforeach (testSrc)
```

Here's a modified example of the output when running `make test`.

```
Running tests...
Test project /mnt/c/Users/me/git/my_lib/cmake-build-debug
    Start 1: test_A
1/7 Test #1: test_A .....................   Passed    0.02 sec
    Start 2: test_B
2/7 Test #2: test_B .........................   Passed    0.02 sec
    Start 3: test_C
3/7 Test #3: test_C ........................   Passed    0.03 sec
    Start 4: test_D
4/7 Test #4: test_D .......................   Passed    0.03 sec
    Start 5: test_E
5/7 Test #5: test_E ........................   Passed    0.02 sec
    Start 6: test_F
6/7 Test #6: test_F ..................   Passed    0.02 sec
    Start 7: test_G
7/7 Test #7: test_G ....................   Passed    0.02 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 7

Total Test time (real) =   0.17 sec
```

I actually want to experiment with flags to get the output to be much more verbose. For example `../tests/testBin/test_A --report_level=detailed`.

```
Running 2 test cases...

Test module "TestModule" has passed with:
  2 test cases out of 2 passed
  39 assertions out of 39 passed

  Test suite "test_x" has passed with:
    2 test cases out of 2 passed
    39 assertions out of 39 passed

    Test case "test_x/y" has passed with:
      34 assertions out of 34 passed

    Test case "test_x/z" has passed with:
      5 assertions out of 5 passed
```

While searching on the internet, some of the top results pass in the flags during `add_test` ([here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/unittests/CMakeLists.txt#L60)) and others during `add_custom_command` (and [here](http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Run-executable-targets-after-change-of-dependency-and-or-every-time-td7586915.html)). I am not sure how they get it to work. Here's some information on my environment.

- cmake v3.10.2
- boost v1.65.1
- g++ v7.4.0

Any ideas on how/where to pass in these flags/arguments to change the output of the tests in a `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for might be [CTest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/manual/ctest.1.html) which provides a [Build And Test Mode](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/manual/ctest.1.html#id18). With this, you should be able to invoke your test command with

```
ctest --build-and-test <path-to-source> <path-to-build>
      --build-generator <generator>
      [<options>...]
      [--build-options <opts>...]
      [--test-command <command> [<args>...]]
```

Make sure to add these two commands in your CMakeLists.txt

```
enable_testing()
include(CTest)
```

With this, you should be able to remove the custom command, and invoke your tests directly using the CTest command.